# Display Graph from Unit Test

Tags: javascript, jenkins, phantomjs

I am using PhantomJS to run a headless test of the load time of my website. I decided to slightly modify the PhantomJS example test [loadspeed.js](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/blob/master/examples/loadspeed.js).

My Code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    t, address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: loadspeed.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    t = Date.now();
    address = system.args[1];
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        } 
        else {
            t = Date.now() - t;
            console.log('Page title is ' + page.evaluate(function () {
                return document.title;
            }));
            //console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
            if(t>7000){
                console.log('Loading time was too long... ' + t + "msec");
                phantom.exit(1);
            }
            else{
                console.log('Loading time ' + t + ' msec');
            }
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

What I would like to do is display the time it took to load the page on a graph in the project page in Jenkins (Time over build#).

I know how to manipulate the build pass/fail by having `phantom.exit()` return a 1 or 0 for exit.

Are there any plugins that can do what I need for this js test or something needed to be added to the loadspeed.js to output the data in a graph for Jenkins to do in Post-Build?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own questions. The parts that you deleted made it into something that was not a question anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Jenkins Plot plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin) - the easiest way to store the data for each build is to write it to a csv file in your build workspace.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Store the value of the time it took to load the page in a csv file?

Comment: Plot Plugin is really simple to set up. Thanks for the link

Comment: I am not able to get the plugin to display the data in my csv file